# strings scanf on pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to receive the names by user. After, I want to print on screen the received the names. For example :

--scan:

```
roy
john
malw
```

--print:

```
roy
john
malw
```

code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    char *aer[4];
    char *(*pter)[4] = &aer;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        scanf(" %s",&(*pter)[i]); //read strings

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("String %d : %s\n",i+1,(*pter)[i]); //write strings

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem and your question?

Comment: The above code does not work

Comment: `char names[4][32];` ... `scanf("%31s", names[i]);`....`printf("%s\n", names[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` is probably not the right function, try with `strtok`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80
#define MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE 4

int main () {
    int i;
    char *aer[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE];
    char s[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    do {
        if (!fgets(s, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin)) return -1;

        i = 0;
        while (
            i != MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE
         && (aer[i] = strtok(i ? 0 : s, " \n"))
        ) i++;

        i = 0;
        while (
            i != sizeof(aer) / sizeof(aer[0])
         && aer[i]
        ) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", aer[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    while (aer[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Also notice that you forgot to allocate memory for the tokens to be parsed. In my example, memory is allocated for the whole line, and strtok returns pointers to substrings inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is also possible with scanf :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char s[4][20+1];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i != 4 && scanf("%20s", s[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    while (j != i) {
        printf("%s\n", s[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But memory still has to be allocated, and also remark that scanf should be given a maximal length.